# Newbie Google Drive API (PHP) confusion - what guide/library to use?

Tags: php, api, google-drive-api

I have a mobile site m.example.com - from a phone I want visitors to choose a file from Google Drive, and send it to the server that hosts m.example.com. Essentially emulating a simple `<input type="file">` file upload as on a desktop.

From what I understand the workflow is as follows:

1) User picks file with Picker which sends meta data of the chosen file to my website client (i.e. the HTML/Javascript running on the phone/tablet)

2) I send that to my server via ajax or just a form hidden field

3) my server makes a request to the Google API to get the file and then stores it in the server's file system

So I need help on:

a) is the above steps correct, and is there any other way to do this, or even a service I can use that will allow my site users to pick their files from one of several cloud storage providors?

a) assuming my steps are correct and this is the only way, I am stuck on the 3) part - server talking to the API.

So far I've ceated the picker as per here - [Google picker auth popup is being blocked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30125804/google-picker-auth-popup-is-being-blocked) and got the file URL. I've not done 2) yet, I'm just manually putting the file URL into my downlaod script for now.

I'm using PHP and the  file I'll want to downlaod to my server could be public or private, that depends on the end user.

I'm lost in the API docs (as in man pages, not a google doc) and am confused with https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/start/get_started (call this API docs)and https://developers.google.com/drive/web/quickstart/quickstart-php (call this Drive docs) - are these two different APIs?

I followed the links from the API docs and installed the client from here : https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client, but when trying "Step 3: Set up the sample" on the Drive docs I get many errors such as files not found, class not fount etc, so that makes me think therr is two different APIs/Clients being documented here - can someone please point me in the right direction to get started?

**UPDATE**

I've re installed the PHP client vis the github linked from this https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/start/get_started

This is that it looks like:

[image]

I ran the simplefileupload.php in the examples directory - worked first time, only had to put in my project details

So went to https://developers.google.com/drive/web/quickstart/quickstart-php#step_3_set_up_the_sample and created drive_rest_api_step_3.php in root of google-api (as shown in screen grab)

Got `Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'src/Google_Client.php' (include_path='.:/usr/local/lib/php') in /path/to/google-api/drive_rest_api_step_3.php on line 5`

There is **no Google_Client.php** in the library, but there **is src/Google/Client.php** so I edit the require_once to use that.

Now get `Failed opening required 'src/contrib/Google_DriveService.php'`  - again a search for that file yeilds no results, **but there is a src/Google/Service/Drive.php,** so edit example to use that:

Requires (on https://developers.google.com/drive/web/quickstart/quickstart-php#step_3_set_up_the_sample) was:

```
require_once 'google-api-php-client/src/Google_Client.php';
require_once 'google-api-php-client/src/contrib/Google_DriveService.php';
```

Now:

```
require_once 'src/Google/Client.php';
require_once 'src/Google/Service/Drive.php';
```

Now getting `Fatal error: Class 'Google_Service' not found in /path/to/google-api/src/Google/Service/Drive.php on line 32`

So this is why I think there is an issues with the two sets of guides, either they use different libraries, or https://developers.google.com/drive/web/quickstart/quickstart-php#step_3_set_up_the_sample is out of date, even though is says Last updated March 30, 2015.

Comment: The docs and github repo you linked are all the same thing, the PHP Client Library for Google Drive. I doubt it's a problem with what you're using and more of how you're using it. I suggest you first begin with getting the quickstart to work. You'll have to share any relevant code and errors if you want help beyond that. It sounds like you probably don't have permission to access the files in question though.

Comment: @Andy - I made an update to my question showing more details and errors, thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are right in that the drive quickstart guide is outdated, it refers to the old version of Google's PHP Client API Library that is on Google Code, rather than the newer one on GitHub. Hence the quickstart guide doesn't work with the PHP Client Library you downloaded. In addition, the quickstart guide code is intended to be executed in PHP command-line mode rather than on the server.

To answer the question, I've put in a few sub-answers:

1. How to use the PHP Client Library
2. How to pick a file with the Google Picker and get the file onto the server

## Using the Google PHP Client Library with the Google Drive API

Try this page instead: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/auth/web-app which has an example showing how to list files on a user's Google Drive using the *new* PHP library, including the whole OAuth procedure.

Unfortunately, even that is a bit outdated (the include path is outdated and is now deprecated). As such (and for StackOverflow's completeness sake) here's some code. I used a subdirectory drivetest in my web server root; change the URLs as necessary.

Do note that you need to get the client ID for "Web applications" in Google's Developer Console, and download the JSON (replacing the `client_secrets.json` in the code as necessary).

**drivetest/quickstart.php**

```
<?php
    require_once 'google-api-php-client/src/Google/autoload.php';

    session_start();

    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setAuthConfigFile('client_secrets.json');
    $client->addScope(Google_Service_Drive::DRIVE_METADATA_READONLY);

    if (isset($_SESSION['access_token']) && $_SESSION['access_token']) {
        $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['access_token']);
        $drive_service = new Google_Service_Drive($client);
        $files_list = $drive_service->files->listFiles(array())->getItems();
        echo json_encode($files_list);
    } else {
        $redirect_uri = 'http://localhost/drivetest/oauth2callback.php';
        header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect_uri, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
    }   

?>
```

**drivetest/oauth2callback.php**

```
<?php
    require_once 'google-api-php-client/src/Google/autoload.php';

    session_start();

    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setAuthConfigFile('client_secrets.json');
    $client->setRedirectUri('http://localhost/drivetest/oauth2callback.php');
    $client->addScope(Google_Service_Drive::DRIVE_METADATA_READONLY);

    if (! isset($_GET['code'])) {
        $auth_url = $client->createAuthUrl();
        header('Location: ' . filter_var($auth_url, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
    } else {
        $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
        $_SESSION['access_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
        $redirect_uri = 'http://localhost/drivetest/quickstart.php';
        header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect_uri, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
    }

?>
```

## Use the Google File Picker to pick files

For your use case, you are probably better off using the Google Picker https://developers.google.com/picker/docs/ which implements the whole browse-and-select-file thing for you, and just gives an ID to the file. A summary of the steps required:

1. Get access token (authentication)
2. Use picker to let user pick file
3. Use file ID returned from picker to get download URL
4. Download file from download URL

We can do this in two ways (client-side or server-side):

### Method 1: Client-side

Using this method, steps 1 - 3 are done in Javascript, and only step 4 is done in PHP. With this method we don't even need the PHP client library!

Here's an example (adapted from sample code in the above link and http://webdevrefinery.com/forums/topic/12931-dropbox-google-drive-file-pickers/):

**picker.html**

This file launches the filepicker upon page load and puts the URL into a form.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
        <title>Google Picker Example</title>


        <script type="text/javascript">

            // The Browser API key obtained from the Google Developers Console.
            var developerKey = '';

            // The Client ID obtained from the Google Developers Console. Replace with your own Client ID.
            var clientId = ""

            // Replace with your own App ID. (Its the first number in your Client ID)
            var appId = ""

            // Scope to use to access user's Drive items.
            var scope = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'];

            var pickerApiLoaded = false;
            var oauthToken;

            // Use the Google API Loader script to load the google.picker script.
            function loadPicker() {
                gapi.load('auth', {'callback': onAuthApiLoad});
                gapi.load('picker', {'callback': onPickerApiLoad});
            }

            function onAuthApiLoad() {
                window.gapi.auth.authorize(
                {
                    'client_id': clientId,
                    'scope': scope,
                    'immediate': false
                },
                handleAuthResult);
            }

            function onPickerApiLoad() {
                pickerApiLoaded = true;
                createPicker();
            }

            function handleAuthResult(authResult) {
                if (authResult && !authResult.error) {
                    oauthToken = authResult.access_token;
                    createPicker();
                }
            }

            // Create and render a Picker object
            function createPicker() {
                if (pickerApiLoaded && oauthToken) {                
                    var view = new google.picker.DocsView();
                    view.setIncludeFolders(true);
                    //view.setMimeTypes("image/png,image/jpeg,image/jpg");

                    var picker = new google.picker.PickerBuilder()
                    //.enableFeature(google.picker.Feature.NAV_HIDDEN)
                    //.enableFeature(google.picker.Feature.MULTISELECT_ENABLED)
                    .setAppId(appId)
                    .setOAuthToken(oauthToken)
                    .addView(view)
                    .setDeveloperKey(developerKey)
                    .setCallback(pickerCallback)
                    .build();
                    picker.setVisible(true);
                }
            }

            // A simple callback implementation.
            function pickerCallback(data) {
                if (data.action == google.picker.Action.PICKED) {
                    var fileId = data.docs[0].id;

                    gapi.client.load('drive', 'v2', function() {
                        var request = gapi.client.drive.files.get({
                            fileId: fileId
                        });
                        request.execute(processFile);           
                    });

                }
            }

            function processFile(file) {
                var token = gapi.auth.getToken();
                // console.log(file);
                // console.log(token);
                document.getElementById("fileurl").value = file.downloadUrl+"&access_token="+token.access_token;
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="submit.php" method="post">
            <label for="fileurl">File Download URL</label><input type="text" name="fileurl" id="fileurl">
            <input type="submit">
        </form>

        <!-- The Google API Loader script. -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js?onload=loadPicker"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

We then submit the form to a PHP script to download the file on the server. The trick here is that we also need to pass the access token from the client to the server, since the user is not authenticated on the server side. Surprisingly, you can simply append the `access_token` parameter to authenticate the download of the file, as shown above.

**submit.php**

Use `file_get_contents` or CURL, depending on what your server supports. HTTPS support is required for this to work though.

```
<?php

    $filename = 'temp.jpg';

    $ch = curl_init($_POST['fileurl']);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    // Should verify in production!
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    //echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    file_put_contents($filename, $data);

?>
```

A more official way (following https://developers.google.com/drive/web/manage-downloads#alternate_method_using_downloadurl) is to send the authorization token separately using the `Authorization` header. Modify the Javascript above to send the download URL and token separately, then use something like the code below instead. If you want to use `file_get_contents`, see [PHP file_get_contents() and headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2107759/php-file-get-contents-and-headers) on how to send custom headers. Note that you *need* to have the `Bearer` word before the token!

```
<?php

    $filename = 'temp.jpg';

    $ch = curl_init($_POST['fileurl']);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Authorization: Bearer '.$_POST['authtoken']));

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);

    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    file_put_contents($filename, $data);

?>
```

### Method 2: Server-side (using PHP)

Using this method, steps 1, 3 and 4 are done in PHP, and only step 2 is done in Javascript.

**quickstart.php**

This page checks if there is an access token in the session, if there is not it redirects the user for authentication. If there is, it shows the picker and a form. In the picker Javascript code, note that the oAuthToken used is obtained with PHP from the server! Source: [Use Google Picker without logging in with Google account (with OAuth)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13413150/use-google-picker-without-logging-in-with-google-account-with-oauth). The form then submits a POST request to this page and the file is downloaded.

```
<?php
    require_once 'google-api-php-client/src/Google/autoload.php';

    session_start();

    // Ref: https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/get
    function downloadFile($service, $file) {
        $downloadUrl = $file->getDownloadUrl();
        if ($downloadUrl) {
            $request = new Google_Http_Request($downloadUrl, 'GET', null, null);
            $httpRequest = $service->getClient()->getAuth()->authenticatedRequest($request);
            if ($httpRequest->getResponseHttpCode() == 200) {
                return $httpRequest->getResponseBody();
                } else {
                // An error occurred.
                return null;
            }
            } else {
            // The file doesn't have any content stored on Drive.
            return null;
        }
    }

    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setAuthConfigFile('client_secrets.json');
    $client->addScope(Google_Service_Drive::DRIVE_READONLY);

    if (isset($_SESSION['access_token']) && $_SESSION['access_token']) {
        $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['access_token']);
        if (isset($_POST['fileid'])){           
            $drive_service = new Google_Service_Drive($client);
            $file = $drive_service->files->get($_POST['fileid']);
            $data = downloadFile($drive_service, $file);
            file_put_contents('temp.jpg', $data);

            echo "file uploaded";
            exit();
        }
    } else {
        $redirect_uri = 'http://localhost/drivepicker-php/oauth2callback.php';
        header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect_uri, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
        exit();
    }   

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
        <title>Google Picker Example</title>


        <script type="text/javascript">

            // The Browser API key obtained from the Google Developers Console.
            var developerKey = '';

            // Replace with your own App ID. (Its the first number in your Client ID)
            var appId = ""

            var pickerApiLoaded = false;

            // Use the Google API Loader script to load the google.picker script.
            function loadPicker() {
                gapi.load('picker', {'callback': onPickerApiLoad});
            }

            function onPickerApiLoad() {
                pickerApiLoaded = true;
                createPicker();
            }

            // Create and render a Picker object
            function createPicker() {
                if (pickerApiLoaded) {              
                    var view = new google.picker.DocsView();
                    view.setIncludeFolders(true);
                    //view.setMimeTypes("image/png,image/jpeg,image/jpg");

                    var picker = new google.picker.PickerBuilder()
                    //.enableFeature(google.picker.Feature.NAV_HIDDEN)
                    //.enableFeature(google.picker.Feature.MULTISELECT_ENABLED)
                    .setAppId(appId)
                    .setOAuthToken('<?= json_decode($client->getAccessToken())->access_token; ?>')
                    .addView(view)
                    .setDeveloperKey(developerKey)
                    .setCallback(pickerCallback)
                    .build();
                    picker.setVisible(true);
                }
            }

            // A simple callback implementation.
            function pickerCallback(data) {
                if (data.action == google.picker.Action.PICKED) {
                    var fileId = data.docs[0].id;
                    document.getElementById("fileid").value = fileId;

                }
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="quickstart.php" method="post">
            <label for="fileid">File ID</label><input type="text" name="fileid" id="fileid">
            <input type="submit">
        </form>

        <!-- The Google API Loader script. -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js?onload=loadPicker"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**oauth2callback.php**

Helper file for the OAuth callback.

```
<?php
    require_once 'google-api-php-client/src/Google/autoload.php';

    session_start();

    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setAuthConfigFile('client_secrets.json');
    $client->setRedirectUri('http://localhost/drivepicker-php/oauth2callback.php');
    $client->addScope(Google_Service_Drive::DRIVE_READONLY);

    if (!isset($_GET['code'])) {
        $auth_url = $client->createAuthUrl();
        header('Location: ' . filter_var($auth_url, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
    } else {
        $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
        $_SESSION['access_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
        $redirect_uri = 'http://localhost/drivepicker-php/quickstart.php';
        header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect_uri, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
    }

?>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed reply. I'm at home now so will not be able to try it till tomorrow. I do have my project setup in the console, but not come across the client_secrets.json you mention - where do I get it from?

Comment: You can get the `client_secrets.json` from https://console.developers.google.com (where you get your IDs and secret). There's a "Download JSON" option once you create the Client ID. It won't be named `client_secrets.json`, but just rename accordingly or change the variable value as you prefer. As a note, this json file is supposed to be secret and should not be in a web-accessible directory in a production environment.

Comment: Ah, I understand, thanks. Also, since the docs are not fully up to date, is the code you posted your own work, or did you get it from somewhere?

Comment: I just modified the sample code I found in the link I placed above: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/auth/web-app where the example (even though it is a page on how to authenticate with the PHP library) happens to show how to use the Google Drive API as well. Then the part about deprecation, a warning was displayed when I used the sample code, so I just modified accordingly following the deprecation notice.

Comment: Once again, thank you for your help. I've got it working using your suggested client side method and simple cURL download PHP - I had actually got the picker working before, but yuo had a few more steps on the picker handler than I had - I would have been using the wrong URL. The way you pass the URL and auth token to cURL - is that based on this link https://developers.google.com/drive/web/manage-downloads#alternate_method_using_downloadurl - again it is not exactly the same, another docs issue perhaps?

Comment: Probably the docs you found are the more accurate/official ones, I found the URL and auth token combination method from another site: http://webdevrefinery.com/forums/topic/12931-dropbox-google-drive-file-pickers/ I have thus updated the answer to include using the authorization header. Not sure how I missed the link you posted, glad to learn from you too!